# TreeSet ignoring values

Tags: java, sorting, treeset

I am trying to create a class that is given pairs of strings & told one is 'greater" than the other then keeps a running order of all known strings.

To do this I keep a `Map<String, Set<String>>` that maps a given `String` to all the values it's greater than, then I created a `TreeSet` with a comparator that uses that data to compare two strings.

Here's my class:

```
public class StringSorter {

    private Map<String, Set<String>> greaterThan = new HashMap<>();
    private SortedSet<String> order;

    public StringSorter() {
        order = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> {
            if (greaterThan.getOrDefault(o1, Collections.emptySet()).contains(o2))
                return 1;
            else if (greaterThan.getOrDefault(o2, Collections.emptySet()).contains(o1))
                return -1;
            return 0;
        });
    }

    public void addRule(String bigger, String smaller) {

        if (!greaterThan.containsKey(bigger))
            greaterThan.put(bigger, new HashSet<>());
        greaterThan.get(bigger).add(smaller);

        order.add(bigger);
        order.add(smaller);
    }

    public SortedSet<String> getOrder() {
        return order;
    }
}
```

However, for some reason, the `TreeSet` seems to just ignore many of the values added to it.

Example:

```
StringSorter sorter = new StringSorter();
sorter.addRule("one", "two");
sorter.addRule("two", "three");
sorter.addRule("three", "four");
System.out.println(sorter.getOrder());
```

Output:

```
[two, one]
```

What happened to the strings `three` & `four`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that set collections keep unique values.
After debugging your comparator you will see that "three" was evaluated as equal to "one", thus forbidding it to be added to the set.

Consider this modification:

```
public StringSorter() {
    order = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> {
        if (greaterThan.getOrDefault(o1, Collections.emptySet()).contains(o2))
            return 1;
        else if (greaterThan.getOrDefault(o2, Collections.emptySet()).contains(o1))
            return -1;
        else if(o1.equals(o2)) return 0;
        else return -1; //or 1, or o1.compareTo(o2)
    });
}
```

Instead of just returning 0 we first check if objects are equal, if not than the comparison itself is irrelevant and result may be arbitrary.

Here is the output when using updated comparator:

```
[four, three, two, one]
```

[Edit]

I would consider changing internal representation of rules to custom oriented tree data structure, represented by sparse adjacency matrix.

Comment: This works for this particular case, but it most certainly will not work for the general case.  A later version of Java is free to change the sorting algorithm and pass "one", "three" instead of "three", "one".  In fact, any different data set might pass elements in a different order.  Blindly returning -1 will not result in correct behavior.

Comment: @VGR As i said, at this point the comparison is irrelevant, we can't say wether either "one" or "three" is greater, because there is no logical connection between them in greaterThan. So any behavior is correct, including returning 1, -1 or o1.compareTo(o2)

Answer (score 1):

You can answer this yourself by adding this line to your Comparator.compare lambda:

```
System.out.printf("(%s, %s)%n", o1, o2);
```

As you’ll see, there is no guarantee that adjacent values are passed to the Comparator.  When `o1` is "three" and `o2` is "one", the comparison falls back to returning zero, which tells the TreeSet that the two values are equal, and obviously it won’t add a value it perceives as equal to a value that’s already in the set.

You would need to make your traversal of `greaterThan` transitive.  I’m pretty sure it will require recursion:

```
private boolean isGreater(String o1,
                          String o2,
                          Set<String> keysTried) {
    Set<String> greaterSet = greaterThan.get(o1);
    if (greaterSet == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (greaterSet.contains(o2)) {
        return true;
    }

    for (String g : greaterSet) {
        if (keysTried.add(g) && isGreater(g, o2, keysTried)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public StringSorter() {
    order = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> {
        if (isGreater(o1, o2, new HashSet<>())) {
            return 1;
        } else if (isGreater(o2, o1, new HashSet<>())) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
}
```

The purpose of `keysTried` is to prevent infinite recursion.  (In theory, that should never happen anyway, if greaterThan is a directed graph.)

Comment: It doesn't, strictly speaking _require_ recursion, just makes it easier to write and read.